# Kendo Chart tooltip number format to 2 decimal places

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-chart

I am working on MVC application
I have the following Kendo chart using razor html

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Chart<Models.Risk>()
              .Name("Risk Based")
              .Title("Risk Based")
              .Legend(legend => legend.Position(ChartLegendPosition.Bottom).ToString())
              //.ChartArea(chart => { chart.Width(500); })
              .DataSource(datasource => datasource
              .Read(read => read.Action("GetRisk", "SevenA",lenderID))
                  )
              .Series(series => { series.Line(d => d.Risk_Based_ch).Name("Risk Based").Color("blue"); })
              .Series(series => { series.Line(d => d.risk_basedpg_ch).Name("Risk Based PeerGroup").Color("lightblue"); })
              .CategoryAxis(axis => axis.Categories(m => m.qiddesc).MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(false)).MajorTicks(lines => lines.Visible(false)).Labels(labels => labels.Visible(false)))
               .ValueAxis(axis => axis
                .Numeric()
                .Min(0).Max(100)
                  .Line(line => line.Visible(true))
                  .PlotBands(bands =>
                  {
                      bands.Add().From(0).To(8).Color("#fa9b4d").Opacity(0.8);
                      bands.Add().From(8).To(10).Color("#ffffff").Opacity(0.8);
                      bands.Add().From(10).To(100).Color("#a3ea62").Opacity(0.3);
                  })
              )
              .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
                  .Visible(true)
                  .Format("{0:N}")
                  .Template("#=dataItem.qiddesc#: #= value #")
              )
    )
```

I would like to format the tooltip upto 2 decimal places. Number stored in database is like 56.989238480 and i want to show this number as 56.98 on the series hover over tooltip.
On the model side formatting on both the series Risk_Based_ch & risk_basedpg_ch are - [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#,0}")]

How can I achieve this formatting in chart tooltip template?

Thanks

Comment: Try `.Format("{0:N2}")` or `.Template("#=dataItem.qiddesc#: #= kendo.toString(value, 'n2') #")`

Comment: Perfect! that worked Thanks Roman Koliada.